# Can you prove that the OS loaded by your BIOS is really your OS?

Tags: operating-systems, audit, bios

Assume you are a paranoic that have a 100% open source OS with drivers etc, but you don't have an alternative to your closed source BIOS.
How can you sure the BIOS didn't insert malicious code in e.g some programs ? You can't trust a program that computes the hash of the memory, since it may have been tampered with also.

Comment: Only somewhat related, but check out the ChromeOS [verified boot procedure](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/security-overview#TOC-Verified-boot).

Comment: I have a good and a bad news for you :) ! The good news is that an [open sources BIOS](https://www.coreboot.org/Welcome_to_coreboot) exists! The bad news is that now that you have a solution for your BIOS, you can to worry about the multiple other firmwares composing your computer (the classical example are network devices) which basically have got the same abilities as the BIOS during boot time and have no OSS alternative... If I remember rightly, I found this video to be interesting: [DEFCON 20: Hardware Backdooring is Practical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Mb4AiZ51Yk).

Comment: You can't, unless you trust your BIOS. After all, it could silently do just about anything it wants without your OS being able to inspect it.

Answer (score 2):

I have highlighted the key part of your question:

> Assume you are a paranoic that have a 100% open source OS with drivers
>   etc, but you **don't have an alternative to your closed source BIOS**. How
>   can you sure the BIOS didn't insert malicious code in e.g some
>   programs ? You can't trust a program that computes the hash of the
>   memory, since it may have been tampered with also.

If you were able to reverse-engineer your BIOS and prove its capabilities, then you should be able to tell whether it could inject malicious code, etc. This would require a great deal of time and skill, but it might be possible, eventually.

In the meantime, **the answer is no: you cannot prove that the OS loaded by your BIOS is the OS you intended.**

For related work, see:

- Matthew Garrett's [`tpmtotp`](https://github.com/mjg59/tpmtotp)
- Trammell Hudson's [additions](https://trmm.net/Tpmtotp) to `tpmtotp`, especially Heads.
- Joanna Rutkowska's [Blue Pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_%28software%29)
- Joanna Rutkowska's [Evil Maid](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/10/evil_maid_attac.html)

Comment: For that matter, it requires a great deal of trust to believe that you're running a faithfully-compiled version of the actual code the legitimate author of the project published and that the hardware is executing it as intended.

Comment: So don't loan your computer to other people.